# When using a field with lookup value, SharePoint says "List not found"

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have this list with a column that refers its values from another column of another list. During the workflow process, the internal status of the workflow becomes **Suspended** with an error:

> Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. 
>   Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 404 
>   {"error":
>   {"code":"-2130575322, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":
>   {"lang":"en-US","value":"List does not exist.\u000a\u000aThe page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."}}}

I reviewed the process and I am very sure that the list is existing (of course, because the workflow itself is working on it). When I excluded the lookup column from the workflow, the workflow completes smoothly. I just wonder because the column is existing and has a value.

Does anyone have encountered this scenario?

Comment: What's "Difficulty: Easy"?

Comment: Hi @Shihan. :D Well, I think that should give the reader an initial idea of the difficulty of the question, although it's hard to categorize the difficulty (because of criteria and such). Anybody can edit my question anyway if that's not acceptable in Stack Exchange. I just tried it. :)

Comment: but the lookup column needs another list, to get the values from. does this list also exist?

Comment: Are those column ootb column type or custom type ?

Comment: Is it possible that list id has been changed? It could happen after creating the list from template. You can try deleting the lookup column and creating it again and reference to the existed list.